# Expanding animation layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I am starting to work with Android Studio and I am having some problems without my activity.

I would like to represent a layout, and after clicking on it, I would like to increase the size of it.

I think that MaterialDesign has a way to do that, but I do not really know how to do it.

I will explain it better with a couple of images:

- Before than clicking on it

[image]

- After clicking on it

[image]

The pictures are made by photoshop, not by coding.

So, what I want to do is to increase the size by the middle of the layout, like in the picture.

I was wondering if someone of you knows how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: read about Set visibility.  you can set visible and gone to views as you need.with the on click you can show the invisible views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution.
Just adding to the `layout` that you want to expand or collapse (and to any of the previous `layouts`) the following line

```
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and working with the visibility of the `layout` you would be able to expand it or collapse it.

Simple method, and it actually works.

**[EDITED]**

The main point of the solution if that you have to code some differents views. Some of the are hidden, and some of them are shown.

The code needed is the followed:

- Java
  Method required to show and hide all the views

  public class Principal_Activity extends AppCompatActivity
          implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  ```
   public void tratar_primer_ranking() {
      //Ranking extendido - cerrado
      RelativeLayout ranking_1_completo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ranking_1_completo);
      ranking_1_completo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              RelativeLayout ocultar_layout_1_1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ocultar_layout_1_1);
              RelativeLayout ocultar_layout_2_1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ocultar_layout_2_1);
              LinearLayout ocultar_layout_4_1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ocultar_layout_4_1);
              if (!extendido_1) {
                  ocultar_layout_1_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  ocultar_layout_2_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  ocultar_layout_4_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  extendido_1 = true;
              } else {
                  ocultar_layout_1_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  ocultar_layout_2_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  ocultar_layout_4_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  extendido_1 = false;
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  }
- XML

  ```
          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/parte_1_ranking_1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

              <ImageView

                  android:id="@+id/verificable_1"
                  android:layout_width="15dp"
                  android:layout_height="15dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/botonrojo" />

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

                  <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/imagen_categoria_1"
                      android:layout_width="60dp"
                      android:layout_height="60dp"
                      android:layout_margin="10dp"
                      android:background="@drawable/categoria_3" />

                  <LinearLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

                      <TextView
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:maxLength="60"
                          android:text="¿Cuántos toques al balón puedes dar con la pierna izquierda?"
                          android:textSize="15sp" />

                      <RelativeLayout
                          android:id="@+id/ocultar_layout_1_1"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                          <LinearLayout
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                              android:orientation="horizontal">

                              <RelativeLayout
                                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                  android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                                  <ImageView
                                      android:layout_width="30dp"
                                      android:layout_height="30dp"
                                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                      android:background="@drawable/ic_perfil" />

                                  <TextView
                                      android:id="@+id/participantes_1_1"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                      android:numeric="integer"
                                      android:text="17" />

                                  <ImageView
                                      android:layout_width="30dp"
                                      android:layout_height="30dp"
                                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                      android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                      android:background="@drawable/actualizacion" />

                                  <TextView
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                      android:text="1d" />
                              </RelativeLayout>
                          </LinearLayout>
                      </RelativeLayout>
                  </LinearLayout>
              </LinearLayout>
          </RelativeLayout> <!--parte_1_ranking_1-->
  ```

Comment: Can you show us your final code? both xml and Java, please

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is something that I have coded long time ago, so I am not sure enough if it is what you are looking for. I guess it will help.

I can not post the hole code cause it is something that I have made for my Thesis, so it is a really long one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "basically", sorry.

The idea is to divide your layout into 3 pieces - ex. top, middle, bottom - and animate "middle" size change. Maybe, middle piece visibility change will also be needed.

The realization may be rather hard, especially if you wish to scroll it back on second click.

My own attempt was based on this example - https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample

Comment: You are right. I know that it is not easy to do it. I will check your example. Thanks!